# Allowing SAS 9.4 to run in memory only

Tags: sas

Forgive me for my ignorance, I am just the IT Manager. I was wondering, is it possible for SAS9.4 to run in memory only?

In my eyes, resources aren't an issue. We have quite literally terabytes of RAM to play with, I just wondered if there was a way to tell SAS to run exclusively in memory and not write any local temp files.

Again, sorry if this is a bit of a silly question.

Tried setting MEMSIZE to MAX

Comment: Make a large ram disk drive and point the WORK folder to a location on that drive.

Comment: @Tom thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping for more of a SAS Viya like model where everything is in memory. SAS documentation is so contradictory, let alone almost impossible to find, I couldn't tell if we would need to purchase SAS Viya to get these benefits. SAS Viya is literally £100,000+ to purchase so trying to find alternative methods! Thanks again

Comment: How about In-Memory Statistics? https://www.sas.com/en_us/software/in-memory-statistics.html

Answer (score 1):

The LIBNAME statement can create memory only libraries.

```
libname    x '<anypath-1>' memlib;
libname work '<anypath-2>' memlib;
```

You will need to specify a startup option to allow a SAS session to use more memory.  *Default is 2GB.*

Settings can be specified in a config file, or on the command line.  MEMSIZE is for the session, and MEMAXSZ is for the memlib in the session.

```
SASFoundation/9.4/sas -MEMSIZE=32GB -MEMMAXSZ=16GB -config <fullname>
```

You can also externally create a RAM disk and specify that at start up

```
SASFoundation/9.4/sas -WORK <memdrivepath> -SASUSER <memdrivepath>
```

There is no magic switch such as -TEXASHOLDEMALLINMEMORY

There are products such as LASR Analytic Server that is a comprehensive in-memory system with concurrency, startup and shutdown features and other administration toolsets.

Answer (score 0):

The in-memory analytical engine behind SAS Viya is CAS (Cloud Analytic Services). It's fault-redundant, high-performance and designed for parallel analytical workloads. SAS 9.4 is designed to use memory as-needed, and creating many temporary tables are typical of SAS 9.4 workloads. This is one reason why SAS is able to handle datasets larger than memory.

I suppose if you [create a RAM disk](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux) you could change the SAS 9 default WORK directory to it and SAS would then be using memory for all temporary tables.

If you'd like an alternative method to use Viya, there is a [pay-as-you-go model for SAS Viya on the Azure marketplace](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/sas-institute-560503.sas-viya-on-azure).